# How to merge all files where specific string was found into one fine in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

This command finds all the files that have string I'm searching for:

```
ls *.log | sls -pattern 'needle'
```

But is there a way to take content from all found files and put it into one file that contains everything?

Comment: Do you want all content from each file or just the matched line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of sls (Select-String) includes path. You can get unique paths (if one file contains several matches) with `Select-Object -Unique Path`. After that you can just pipe it to `Get-Content` to get content instead of filename and stream the result into a file using `>`. Full command will be something like:

ls *.log | sls -pattern 'needle' | Select-Object -Unique Path | Get-Content > result

Comment: Thanks! At first this screwed up text in files, but after I replaced "> result" with " | Add-Content -Path file.txt" it started to work fine.